# How to Added objects in SceneKit SWIFT

Tags: xcode, swift, blender, scenekit

I have 2 files that I imported from Blender(3D design program) they are both .dae specifically they are "CampusField1.dae" CampusField is the ground/floor of the game and "Bob.dae" is the Man/character. My question is when I set CampusField1 as the scene how do I get "Bob" in the scene too. And the other question is lets say I export the .dae from blender now I put the file in the game... every things good but then is the animation for Bob already attached to the Bob.dae file or do I have to export something else from blender so that I can run the animation because I don't know what the animation ID would be or how to actually make it run and to actually make Bob do something.

Code:

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore
import SceneKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/CampusField1.dae")!

    let src = SCNSceneSource(URL: yourSceneURL, options: nil)
    let node = src.entryWithIdentifier("Bob", withClass: SCNNode.self) as SCNNode
    let animation = node.entryWithIdentifier("yourAnimationID", withClass: CAAnimation.self) as CAAnimation
```

Full GameController Below!:

```
  import UIKit
  import QuartzCore
  import SceneKit

   //============================================================
  class GameViewController: UIViewController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //-------------------------
    let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/CampusField1.dae")!

    let src = SCNSceneSource(URL: yourSceneURL, options: nil)
    let node = src.entryWithIdentifier("Bob", withClass: SCNNode.self) as SCNNode
    let animation = node.entryWithIdentifier("yourAnimationID", withClass: CAAnimation.self) as CAAnimation
    //--------------------------
    let cameraNode = SCNNode()
    cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
    cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 15)
    //-----------------------------------------------
    let lightNode = SCNNode()
    lightNode.light = SCNLight()
    lightNode.light!.type = SCNLightTypeOmni
    lightNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 10, z: 10)
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode)
    //-----------------------------------------------
    let ambientLightNode = SCNNode()
    ambientLightNode.light = SCNLight()
    ambientLightNode.light!.type = SCNLightTypeAmbient
    ambientLightNode.light!.color = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(ambientLightNode)
    //----------------------------------------------
    //_ = scene.rootNode.childNodeWithName("Bob", recursively: true)!
    // _ = scene.rootNode.childNodeWithName("CampusField1", recursively: true)!

    //--------------------------------------------------------
    // Bob.runAction(SCNAction.repeatActionForever(SCNAction.rotateByX(0, y: 2, z: 0, duration: 1)))

    let scnView = self.view as! SCNView

    scnView.scene = scene

    scnView.allowsCameraControl = true
    scnView.showsStatistics = false
    scnView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTap:")
    scnView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }

func handleTap(gestureRecognize: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    let scnView = self.view as! SCNView
    let p = gestureRecognize.locationInView(scnView)
    let hitResults = scnView.hitTest(p, options: nil)
    if hitResults.count > 0 {
        let result: AnyObject! = hitResults[0]
        let material = result.node!.geometry!.firstMaterial!
        SCNTransaction.begin()
        SCNTransaction.setAnimationDuration(0.5)
        SCNTransaction.setCompletionBlock {
            SCNTransaction.begin()
            SCNTransaction.setAnimationDuration(0.5)
            material.emission.contents = UIColor.blackColor()
            SCNTransaction.commit()
        }
        material.emission.contents = UIColor.yellowColor()
        SCNTransaction.commit()
    }
}
    //==================================================
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return true
}
 //============================
    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
       return true
   }
 //==========================
   override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() ->    UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
        return .AllButUpsideDown
        } else {
           return .All
      }
     }
      //=============================
       override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
     }

   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to tell you is you have got two SCNScene; CampusField and Bob. Therefore you need to take out the character node from the Bob scene.

[image]

You need to name the node as like from the above figure. And extract that node from the scene as:

```
let bobScene = SCNScene(named: "Bob.dae") 
let bobNode = personScene?.rootNode.childNodeWithName("person", recursively: true) 
let campusFieldScene = SCNScene(named: "CampusField1.dae") 
campusFieldScene.rootNode.addChildNode(bobNode)
```

Comment: awesome would you by any chance know how to animate the skinned character i looked into it and i think I'm really close. I think i would put my character in the scene then from there load a animation from a separate .dae/Collada file with the same character just him doing like a walking animation. idk?

Comment: There are two ways to do the walking animation:1. Either you export animating character from the 3d modelling software like blender or maya. 2. Or you name the individual nodes and animate those nodes using core animation... :]